# What is the right way to save the process instance id(s) created?

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Using Camunda as the tool for orchestration of the microservices. At later time, I find the process_instances_id generated necessary for continuing a particular process by using it in messageEventReceived(). Code as follows:

```
 val processid = getProcessID(key1, key2)
 val runtimeService = processengine.getRuntimeService
 val subscription = runtimeService.createEventSubscriptionQuery
    .eventType("message")
    .eventName(eventname)
    .processInstanceId(executionid)
    .singleResult
 runtimeService.messageEventReceived(subscription.getEventName, subscription.getExecutionId)
```

As of this moment the **processid** is saved and then retrieved from the database using the *getProcessID(...)* function when necessary. Is this proper?

Does camunda already have the list of process_ids in its own database? If so, how do I retrieve a particular process instance id just giving composite key(s)? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is the common way. You can also use the public api to get the process instance and his id via the process definition key.

See the following example from the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/process-engine-concepts/#query-for-process-instances):

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
    .processDefinitionKey("invoice")
    .list();
```

For your given example there is also a simpler way. It is possible to correlate the message via the runtime service.

See this example from the [documenation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/#using-the-runtime-service-s-correlation-methods):

```
runtimeService.createMessageCorrelation("messageName")
  .processInstanceBusinessKey("AB-123")
  .setVariable("payment_type", "creditCard")
  .correlate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().list();
```

the query supports fluent criteria for filtering, for example on process_key, variables, businessKey ...